# Autocomplete component returns undefined error in React app

Tags: html, reactjs, combobox, html-select

I am trying to insert an autocomplete component in my react app and I get the error:

```
The `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for "Score".
```

whenever I try to select an option.

Here is the autocomplete code:

```
<Autocomplete
  id="id"
  options={["Score","Name"]}
  getOptionLabel={option=> option.label}
  style={{width:300}}
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField {...params} label="Sort By" variant="outlined" />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `options` as an array of strings (`["Score","Name"]`)
Then passing `getOptionLabel` as `option => option.label`, but your options are plain strings.

Either try removing `getOptionLabel` prop, or update items in your  `options` array as objects with `label` property.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by creating a list of objects with the property label and then the names ,and in the getoptionlabel i wrote option.label